# How to edit Linux containers configs and observe it hashes in Docker Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, phpstorm

I installed *Docker* on *Windows*. It's switched to `Switched to Linux containers`.

When I type in my console: `docker inspect e3a934c54979` I see an information:

```
[
    {
        ...
        "Image": "sha256:2359fa12fdedef2af79d9b836a26175808d4b1433b5e7022d2d73c72b2a43b60",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/e3a934c549799d9ec45d65ad6aa73bba8fad924215087a9c9c60535ef2a5c2e8/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/e3a934c549799d9ec45d65ad6aa73bba8fad924215087a9c9c60535ef2a5c2e8/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/e3a934c549799d9ec45d65ad6aa73bba8fad924215087a9c9c60535ef2a5c2e8/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/e3a934c549799d9ec45d65ad6aa73bba8fad924215087a9c9c60535ef2a5c2e8/e3a934c549799d9ec45d65ad6aa73bba8fad924215087a9c9c60535ef2a5c2e8-json.log",
        "Name": "/festive_edison",          
        ...
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            ...
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/10f5348d5bfa76612ab30d1a253f17a6989fcd3f7ce23642b313c49f99a95f44-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/028eac1b0f37fd3be798d222f7d1da48a40f0ef9c4470709e63c4c8f322a477f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d15e7ce0f29f82d6d3b9537980b766c32e7f6ffc81374cdb26fede3872afed1e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/efab543606225e581832ef6e2b732a78c82b2f6d9fe662babe09b188f600dd72/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/263366359e8a86cc6c009f70fa00a158dbcbcfd2a4e31d9538c559dd82e29b10/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/32ea6c48b53f4846284e1baac83dffcfb039a53a8d2f33ac2728691160f5d100/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/685745d44609453debf484b2ccf63035532b334e75b9f18a00c5e1253e18841a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e30c0a304544255bc9eba90dfb720c332e168b4972df926a79ef27df707889fd/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a5743532bc060895f0a495249182787322400a1a33fd187b3210895e1ca83129/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/10f5348d5bfa76612ab30d1a253f17a6989fcd3f7ce23642b313c49f99a95f44/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/10f5348d5bfa76612ab30d1a253f17a6989fcd3f7ce23642b313c49f99a95f44/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/10f5348d5bfa76612ab30d1a253f17a6989fcd3f7ce23642b313c49f99a95f44/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        ...
    }
]
```

But *Windows* doesn't have those directories. It only has "MobyLinuxVM.vhdx" which, I think, contains this stuff.

My question is how to edit "config.json" and "hostconfig.json" in this case? How do I view  a GUID-json.log? How do I view container's hashes (`/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff`)?

Answer (score 1):

Information from https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/11/ssh-into-docker-vm-windows/

In a Windows command prompt enter:

> docker run --privileged -it -v
> /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
> jongallant/ubuntu-docker-client
>
> docker run --net=host --ipc=host --uts=host --pid=host -it
> --security-opt=seccomp=unconfined --privileged --rm -v /:/host alpine /bin/sh
>
> chroot /host

From here you'll have access to the /var/lib/Docker/containers/ directories for the hostconfig.json and other files.